# SQLALchemy ORM Query takes very long to run - with a very mild alteration in subquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two versions of a subquery using SQLAlchemy ORM:

```
subq1 = session.query(su.DistCode,dr.RtrId, su.RtrCode, su.InvoiceNo, su.SlabId, sh.SchId, sslab.PurQty, sslab.DiscPer, sslab.FlatAmt).\
    join(sh).\
    join(dr, and_(dr.DistCode==su.DistCode, dr.RtrCode==su.RtrCode)).\
    join(sslab,and_(su.SlabId==sslab.SlabId, sh.SchId==sslab.SchId)).\
    subquery()
```

and the other being:

```
subq1 = session.query(su.DistCode,dr.RtrId, su.RtrCode, su.InvoiceNo, su.SlabId, sh.SchId).\
    join(sh).\
    join(dr, and_(dr.DistCode==su.DistCode, dr.RtrCode==su.RtrCode)).\
    subquery()
```

The only difference between the two is the inclusion of a join with:

```
.join(sslab,and_(su.SlabId==sslab.SlabId, sh.SchId==sslab.SchId))
```

I use both versions with the following code, one after the other.

```
subq2 = session.query(ds.DistCode, ds.RtrId, ds.PrdCde, ds.SalInvDte, ds.SalInvNo,
                     (ds.SalInvQty*ds.SelRateBeforTax).label('SBT'), ds.SalInvSch, 
                     pdet.ProductId, dr.RtrChannelCode, dr.GeoName, dr.RtrClassCode, dr.RtrCode,
                     dr.RtrGroupCode).join(pdet).outerjoin(dr, and_(ds.DistCode==dr.DistCode, ds.RtrId==dr.RtrId)).subquery()

rset = session.query(subq2.c.DistCode, subq2.c.RtrId, subq2.c.RtrCode, subq2.c.SalInvNo,
                     subq2.c.SalInvDte, subq2.c.PrdCde, subq2.c.ProductId, subq2.c.SBT, subq2.c.SalInvSch,
                     subq2.c.RtrChannelCode, subq2.c.RtrClassCode, subq2.c.RtrGroupCode,
                     subq2.c.GeoName, subq1.c.SlabId, subq1.c.SchId).join(subq1,and_(subq1.c.DistCode==subq2.c.DistCode, subq1.c.RtrId==subq2.c.RtrId, subq1.c.InvoiceNo==subq2.c.SalInvNo)).join(spid,and_(subq2.c.ProductId==spid.ProductID, subq1.c.SchId==spid.SchemeID))

df = pd.read_sql(rset.statement, rset.session.bind)
```

The results gobsmack me. The first query gets into an infinite loop (or something that takes 10 hours+; while the other takes all of 26 seconds!

As a way of debugging through this issue, I ran both versions of 'subq1' as independent queries and both work absolutely fine - running in less than 3 seconds.

Any ideas on how I can get to the bottom of this issue?

Comment: You consider adding an other join a "mild alteration"?

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` or your DBMS' equivalent to inspect the query plans and estimates. SQL rarely results in infinite loops unless using recursive CTE, but wrong joins may result in ridiculous amounts of rows to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In today's world of quantum computing and self driven cars, I would expect multiple joins to be a simple problem. Turns out it is.

My colleague suggested this answer and it worked. I was missing out on group_by. group_by on subquery apparently reduces processing time significantly.

All I had to do was alter subq1 as:

```
 subq1 = session.query(su.DistCode,dr.RtrId, su.RtrCode, su.InvoiceNo, su.SlabId, 
                          sh.SchId, sslab.PurQty.label('PQ'), 
                      sslab.DiscPer.label('DP'), 
                      sslab.FlatAmt.label('FA')).join(sh).join(dr, and_(dr.DistCode==su.DistCode, dr.RtrCode==su.RtrCode)).join(sslab,and_(su.SlabId==sslab.SlabId, sh.SchId==sslab.SchId)).group_by(su.DistCode,dr.RtrId, su.RtrCode, su.InvoiceNo, su.SlabId, sh.SchId, sslab.DiscPer, sslab.FlatAmt, sslab.PurQty).subquery()
```

**Notice the group_by at the end. Worked like a charm. runs in less than a minute.**

Comment: Pure speculation since you have not provided a sample of your data, but perhaps your joins produce duplicate rows in such amounts that the further joins then take forever, and the grouping eliminates the dupes. Just using `DISTINCT` would have the same effect.

Comment: Also, multiple joins is anything but a simple problem. In an n-table join there are *n!* ways to join. Add to that all the different ways to apply predicates etc., and the number of possible query plans grows ridiculously fast.